# Make labelled FlatIcons draggable?

Tags: google-maps

I'm creating a Google map to display multiple points with each point having a short text label. I found a JavaScript library that lets me label the markers easily. I would also like to make the markers draggable. I'm working from this example.

<s>http://gmaps-utility-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/mapiconmaker/1.1/examples/createflaticon-simple.html</s>

I tried the following, but it doesn't work, at least in Firefox 3.04.

```
var newIcon = MapIconMaker.createFlatIcon({ draggable: "true", label: "12300" });

var point = new GLatLng(43.82589,-79.10040);

var marker = new GMarker(point, {icon: newIcon});

map.addOverlay(marker);

marker.enableDragging();
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/?exp=maps#map_marker_drag

This should get ya there
Cheers